# Running android project with ADT frequently restarts phone device

Tags: java, android, linux, eclipse, adt

I'm not sure if it's the `ide/sdk` or phone issue but really offen I face the problem with device restart when running `android` project(after `build`, during `installation` process).

The project has about `10` external `libs` with `40mb` size overall. I've checked that device has enough space for app besides this doesn't happen every time. It's about `1 per 5 runs`.

**Environment:**

`ubuntu 12.04 x64,adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321, lenovo a820`

**EDIT:**
Might it be the issue of logs amount? There's about 5k lines in 15 sec.

**EDIT:**
Recently the same problem occured with much smaller project (like 1.5Mb) using Google Maps v2(glEsVersion) and android annotations (preprocesor compiler). Might those libs cause this issue?

Comment: Quite a big app. Which phone do you use ? An old cow or something recent ?

Comment: It's rather new device. Original 4.1.2 android version.

Comment: try to keep a copy of the logs : open a shell and let `adb logcat` run while the device reboots and check the logs.

Comment: Not a real answer, but the way I workaround these kind of problems is using genymotion. Not good for testing, but for development is very good.

Comment: @GaRRaPeTa some offtop from me. What's the advantage of geanymotion against real device and google emulators?

Comment: It's faster to deploy in. Google emulator are really slow... on the other hand you need to pay for a license if you are using it commercially.

Answer (score 0):

when I have problems with a device I install [pdaNet](http://pdanet.co/) to connect with. I hope it helps you.